# WCF service with data contract accessing issue

Tags: c#, wcf

I am very new to **WCF** programmng and having some difficulties.

I have client application which collects `student` data and then that `student` data will be stored to the DB through a `web services`.

So I have `student class` in client side and when new student comes I create the student object and assigned collected values.

**What is the most suitable way to pass this data to the services??**

Options that I can follow is;

**Option 1**

```
public void InsertStudent(string id, string name, string address)  
{  
}
```

I feel this is not good. Because if I have to pass so may data the parameter list will get lengthy.

**Option 2**

define a data contract on service

```
public void InsertStudent(WcfStudent obj)  
{

}
```

I feel this is good. But I have some issues with how to send the parameter(`WcfStudent`). 
Do I need to create this `WcfStudent` object on my client side and pass the object.

```
WcfStudent obj=new WcfStudent()

obj.name=myStudent.name;

obj.id=myStudent.id;

client.InsertStudent(obj);
```

is this the correct way to to do this??

Please advice me.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Create the WcfStudent client side and pass it to the WCF service Operation that is specifically written to store it

Comment: Use the WSDL to generate your client. This will create the RPC to send to the WCF Endpoint.

Comment: @Steve- I am having some unsureness. I want to make sure is it ok to create the `WcfStudent` in the client side. Because I already have `myStuden`t object with same data.

Comment: @New Developer- like I wrote in post below. Map myStudent object to WcfStudent object. It's good to have in business logic different (even if structure is the same) object than in WCF. Like you know it's good to seperate application to some layers.

Comment: ...except for the problem of too many layers of indirection.

Answer (score 2):

Of course like you said second option is better. In WCF Project you have to create DataContract WcfStudent. In project which have service reference (this is what you call client) you have to just execute method (OperationContract) InsertStudent. How you create this object in theory it doesn't matter but I think it's a good practice to have in your 'client' also an object named for example StudentBO and create mapping between WcfStudent and StudentBO or use some tool for example Automapper.

If you're totally new in WCF please read about DataContract, DataMember.

Good luck!

**UPDATE**

Speaking about your comment would be better something like:

```
public WcfStudent(MyStudent myStudent)
{
    this.Id= myStudent.Id;
    this.Name= myStudent.Name;
}
```

Comment: The way I crate `WcfStudent` object as above is fine or is there any standard way to do that?

Comment: I think would be better to create constructor with one parameter MyStudent: public WcfStudent(MyStudent myStudent){ //mapping between objects here}

Comment: where should I place this constructor.n client side or WCF service side?

Comment: Wcf side. Or you can create in client side for example in MyStudent class method: ToWcfObject() which will do the same (return WcfStudent)

Answer (score 0):

Your WCF Service will contain the definition of your WcfStudent class, and it will define that class as a Data Contract (if you are not using separate DTOs).

Referencing the WCF Service in your client project, either via a WSDL file or via the Visual Studio interface, gives your client application visibility or knowledge on the public classes, interfaces, and whatnot of the Service. This should include the WcfStudent class. You can then proceed with utilizing this in your code through something like:

```
MyWcfService.WcfStudent student = new MyWcfService.WcfStudent();
//assign values, etc
```

Manipulate that student object inside your application as you see fit, and then call your web service when you are ready to persist.

```
client.InsertStudent (student);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would typically use data contracts instead of individual parameters, because then you can easily version them; and extend them easily with additional optional parameters and still be backwards compatible.

Personally I like to follow the request/response pattern consistently:

```
public InsertStudentResponse InsertStudent(InsertStudentRequest request)  
{  
}
```

If you don't expect a result, the response type could be void of course.

The request object contains **only what you need in order to complete te request**. Nothing more, nothing less. For example, if you want to change the address of a student, don't call ModifyStudent while passing all student properties, but call MoveStudent and pass only the new address information; so that you have clearly defined business operations.

Concerning the naming of your operations, `InsertStudent` is a CRUD-like naming, while I prefer to name them in business terminology, like `RegisterNewStudent` or something.

Also don't forget about fault contracts: don't throw exceptions, throw faults.